# Curator 5.x with Zookeeper client 3.5.x and Zookeeper server 3.4.x

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, compatibility, backwards-compatibility, apache-curator

[ZooKeeper 3.4.x is no longer supported by Curator 5.x](https://curator.apache.org/breaking-changes.html)

But does it mean that i can't use neither Zookeeper client nor Zookeeper server 3.4.x ?

I wounder if somewhere is compatibility matrix  between Curator, Zookeeper-Client and Zookeeper-Server? It would be very helpful, but i didn't find anything like that by googling

Answer (score 1):

If you want/need to continue to use ZooKeeper 3.4.x with Curator you must use Curator 4.2.x as described here: https://curator.apache.org/zk-compatibility-34.html